# what is the Regular Expressions to use to find if a line contain a word?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I would like to check in my script if in a line   i have the word device  i tried  this regex

`if[$SERIAL =~ /device/]`   but the execution result commande  unkown. this is my script i try to install apk in only devices that present the stat device so not ofline, you find my script below

```
for SERIAL in $(adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1);
do 
    if [$SERIAL =~ /device/]
    #if [$SERIAL = "/^.*/device\b.*$/m"]
    then
        cd $1
        for APKLIST in $(ls *.apk);
        do
            echo "Installation de  $APKLIST on $SERIAL"
            adb -s  $SERIAL install -r $1/$APKLIST &
            #adb bugreport > bug.txt
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Are you looking for the devices whose serial number contains "device" substring or just devices with "device" on the same line in "adb devices" output vs devices with let's say "offline"?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your if line into:

```
if [[ $SERIAL =~ "device" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `| cut -sf 1` your $SERIAL variable is going to contain just the serial number. So why are you trying to match it against `device`? It is never going to be `true`. Why won't you  just use

```
for SERIAL in $(adb devices | grep device$ | cut -sf 1);
```

instead of your `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You ***must*** always put a space between the square brackets in your `if` statement and what you're testing. You must also understand there are two types of square brackets, the `[ ... ]` standard and the expanded `[[ ... ]]`.

The `[` is actually a Unix command which is aliased to the `test`<sup>1</sup> command:

```
$ ls -li /bin/test /bin/[
54008404 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 Jul 25  2012 /bin/[
54008404 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 Jul 25  2012 /bin/test
```

You can see the basic tests by looking at the [`test` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Both Kornshell (which started it) and BASH give you the expanded test using double square brackets (`[[ ... ]]`). The `[[ ... ]]` is mainly used for [pattern matching](http://arcib.dowling.edu/cgi-bin/info?%28bash%29Pattern%2520Matching). Pattern matching extends the globbing that the shell can do on the command line -- sort of a poor man's regular expression. Newer versions of BASH actually allow you to use real regular expressions rather than *pattern matching*.

The important thing to remember is that you must use the double square brackets whenever you are doing a pattern match testing (or regular expression testing in BASH) rather than the single square brackets which can only test strings.

Also remember that regular expressions can match anywhere on a line:

```
if [[ $SERIAL =~ "device" ]]
```

could match `devices`. What you want to do is to add `\b` to make sure you're matching the word `device`. The `\b` is a regular expression word boundary:

```
if [[ $SERIAL =~ "\bdevice\b" ]]
```

---

<sup>1.</sup> Yes, I know the `[` is a shell builtin in BASH and Kornshell, and `[` doesn't execute `/bin/[`. However, the `test` command is also a shell builtin too.